# Android Ormlite upgrade issue with ForeignCollectionField

Tags: android, ormlite

While upgrading my database schema I have run into a problem with a ForeignCollectionField (ormlite 4.7) not returning rows. With a clean install of the app, rows can be added and displayed as expected.

When the app is updated to a new version, the schema is updated (see below), but when rows are added to the database the collection is not returning the added rows. (I can see the rows exist in the database)

The parent row existed before the update.  What do I need to do to fix it?

**Parent class with Foreign Collection defined**

```
@DatabaseTable(tableName = "setting")
public class SettingEntity {

    @DatabaseField(generatedId = true)
    private long id;

    …

    //New field added
    @ForeignCollectionField
    private ForeignCollection<DistributionEntity> distribution;

    public SettingEntity() {
        // Required for ORMLite
    }

    public ForeignCollection<DistributionEntity> getDistribution() {
        return distribution;
    }

    public void setDistribution(ForeignCollection<DistributionEntity> distribution) {
        this.distribution = distribution;
    }
}
```

**Child class**

```
@DatabaseTable(tableName = "distribution")
public class DistributionEntity {

    @DatabaseField(generatedId = true)
    private long id;
    …
    //New field added
    @DatabaseField(canBeNull = true, foreign = true, index = true, foreignAutoRefresh = true, columnDefinition = "integer references setting(id) on delete cascade")
    private SettingEntity setting;

    public void setSetting(SettingEntity setting) {

        this.setting = setting;
     }
 }
```

**onUpgrade code**

```
RuntimeExceptionDao<DistributionEntity, Integer> distributionDao = helper.getDistributionDao();
distributionDao.executeRaw("ALTER TABLE distribution ADD setting_id");
distributionDao.executeRaw("CREATE INDEX distribution_setting_idx ON distribution (setting_id)");
```

**Debug info of the ForeignCollectionField call distribution**

[image]

**The code that iterates over the collection**

```
public ArrayList<Distribution> getDistribution() {
    getEntity().getDistribution().size();
    final ArrayList<Distribution> items = new ArrayList<Distribution>();
    final ForeignCollection<DistributionEntity> collection = getEntity().getDistribution();
    for (final DistributionEntity item : collection) {
        final Distribution dist = new Distribution(item, mContext);
        items.add(dist);
    }
    return items;
 }
```

NB getEntity() returns an instance of SettingEntity

Thanks for spending the time

Comment: Sorry for the old response.  So you are adding a setting_id field to the distribution but I don't see you setting the value of setting_id to the appropriate `setting.id` field for existing data.  Is that done somewhere else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

More of a workaround than answer but had to get around this problem.  Replicated behavior by writing code.

```
public List<DistributionEntity> getDistribution() {

    List<DistributionEntity> distributionEntities = new ArrayList<DistributionEntity>();

    try {
        DatabaseHelper helper = DatabaseHelper.getInstance();
        RuntimeExceptionDao<DistributionEntity, Integer> dao = helper.getDistributionDao();

        QueryBuilder<DistributionEntity, Integer> queryBuilder = dao.queryBuilder();
        queryBuilder.where().eq(DistributionEntity.SETTING_FIELD_NAME, Long.toString(this.getId()));
        PreparedQuery<DistributionEntity> preparedQuery = queryBuilder.prepare();
        distributionEntities = dao.query(preparedQuery);

    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return distributionEntities;
    //return distribution;
}
```

Love to know what the true answer is